# The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, angular7

I have created and published angular 7 with asp.net core 2.1 application on server and it is working perfectly without any issue. But when I published same application to another server then I got following error

> The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be
>   evaluated locally.

I have used count function and also group by in the query.
I have searched and got various types of answers related to not use group by in ef query where not necessary, but I want to ask why this code is not working on this server where it was working on previous server? Is there any server related issue or version conflict issue?

Comment: Try publishing it with runtime identifier and the publish output would contain the runtime, then the behaviour among machines (on the same platform) would be similar. `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release` or for Windows, `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release`

Comment: I think you forgot to include your [mcve].

Comment: I've always understood this to be a warning rather than an error. It means your query is too complex for the ORM to translate it into a COUNT query that will execute on the server and instead the client will drag all the rows out over the network and count them when they arrive. This could be a serious performance hit, as if you have a million rows, it's certainly faster to have the db count then and return a single integer than it is to download a million rows worth of data just so it can be counted then discarded

Comment: I tried publishing with runtime identifier but still same error

Comment: @Caius Jard but this query is working fine on previous server

Comment: Previous server was a different server?

Comment: @Caius Jard The OS is same (windows 2012 R2) but i buy space on new server